# Naming MVVM classes

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, architecture

How do you name the classes (Model, View, ViewModel) using the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel) pattern in your projects?

Comment: Thanks to all advance, I will mark answers after receiving several responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the view I append 'View' to the Model, as in "PersonView".

Similarly for the view model I append 'Vm' to get "PersonVm".

Of course the The Model name has everything to do with the domain and nothing to do with MVVM.

Cheers,
Berryl